# Find a specific String in a range and copy it to another field in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to find a specific string in a range, get its address and copy its value into a new cell, which depends on the old address

Here is what I've tried until now:

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("F1:F1500")
    If InStr(1, c.Text, "Overall Result") Then
        Range(c).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range(newAddress).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next c
```

But I'm not sure about how to get the right address of the cell. The new cell should be the old address.row and the old address.column+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)` to move one column right outgoing from the range `c`.

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("F1:F1500")
    If InStr(1, c.Text, "Overall Result") Then
        c.Cut Destination:=c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
    End If
Next c
```

Also have a look at [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) which is a bad practice, slows you down and is not very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("F1:F1500")
    If InStr(1, c.Text, "Overall Result") Then
        Range(c.address).offset(0,1).value = c.text
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: `Range(c.address)` Making a address out of a range to make a range out of that address seems to be a bit cumbersome if you can use the range directly.